# Who are famous free time composers/pianists other than Erik Satie?

Tags: piano

I really really love Erik Satie's work.

I have been trying to find other music resembling gnossiennes. On its Wikipedia page, it is defined as being part of **free time** (lacking time signatures or bar divisions). But I am unable to find any other music categorised as this.
Can someone help?

Comment: The Gnossiennes are written without bar lines, but there are very obvious bar divisions in the music so they can hardly be described as "free time". If you like these pieces then you'd probably like Satie's other music.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wikipedia page for [Free time (music)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_time_(music)) lists  Charles Ives' Concord Sonata, and most of Kaikhosru Shapurji Sorabji's music alongside Erik Satie as examples. There are a few more contemporary examples in the article, it is worth a full read.

[Free jazz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_jazz) and [Free Improvisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_improvisation) are also related and mentioned in the article, although don't really give many examples that would resemble Satie's music.

This [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/classicalmusic/comments/1fupzf/looking_for_composers_similar_to_erik_satie/) asking the same question is helpful, mentioning Debussy, Frederic Mompou, Ravel, Poulenc, and many others. Personally I think that Ravel's work most closely relates to Satie's.

Free time is generally much harder to perform, describe, and relate to a listener so it does make sense that its use is much more limited compared to other more common rhythmic devices.